# is it possible tracking all authentication requests on AD Server?

Tags: active-directory

is it possible tracking all authentication requests on AD Server? no matter the requests go through LDAP, Kerberos or NTLM, and getting know the source IP address and account name?

Answer (score 1):

That information is already in the Event Viewer on each of your domain controllers.

If you search online, you may be able to find some software that can be installed on each DC that will consolidate all that information for you to make it easier to look at and search. But I've never done that, so I can't recommend anything.